# How would you trigger some code upon the completion of a resque worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, backgroundworker, resque

I want to execute some ruby code once a resque worker has finished. I found the [resque-status](https://github.com/datagraph/resque-status) gem that lets you get the status of a worker, but how would I execute some code once the status changes from `working` to `completed`?

Answer (score 1):

This should be handled outside the scope of the worker job itself.
Typically you would want to create an observer on an attribute of the data that the worker modifies.

For example if your worker is working on a traditional ActiveRecord model, you could define an after_update method in the model (or an observer on that model with an after_update method).
It would be up to you to decide what to check in the model to determine the job state (complete, still working, etc).

Alternatively you could create a state attribute on the model, and the worker would update the model state using traditional AASM-style calls.  State transition callbacks would handle the working->completed events.